Preserving Subrows Visibility When Filtering Parent Rows in Material React Table
I’m currently working on a project using Material React Table v1, and I’ve encountered an issue with filtering. According to the TanStack documentation here and MRT documentation here, enabling the filterFromLeafRows option will include parent rows if any of their child or grand-child rows are included in the filter results.
However, when I enable this option, I’ve noticed that when searching for the parent row itself, the children rows are filtered out, which isn’t the desired behavior. I would like to preserve the visibility of subrows even when searching for the parent row.
Is there a way to adjust the filtering behavior so that subrows are preserved and visible when searching for the parent row?
